# Ajax request through DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, spring-mvc

i hope that you will help me with my simple problem.

I have configured spring mvc application which have been configured from simple jsf application. I use primefaces libraries.

I have a controller and it handles request from welcome.do requests and ViewResolver finds by rule with prefix /ui/ and postfix .xhtml. Simple and common used configuration.

@RequestMapping("/*.do")
 public void actionDo(){
  logger.debug("invoked");
 }
The first requests are handled corectly, but when i generate ajax request from welcome form to some sessionBean , it generates warning:

```
[2011-01-18 21:28:28,442] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService DispatcherServlet with name 'springDispatcher' processing POST request for [/prime/ui/welcome.do] 
[2011-01-18 21:28:28,443] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/prime/ui/welcome.do] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springDispatcher'
```

So, it tries to find view by name /ui/welcome.do and can't, because ajax request don't matches the rules of my request handling.  Should DispatcherServlet handle ajax requests or not?

I think that it is very common problem and it can be resolved simply, but i don't know how. without Spring MVC everything works fine. So, can you tell my the good practices for passing ajax requests through DispatcherServlet?

A part of my web.xml file.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Thank you!

Comment: that sounds very odd - why spring mvc AND jsf? what is the dispatcher servlet mapped to, and what is the jsf servlet mapped to.

Comment: because primefaces has many good-loking components. Is using spring mvc and jsf libraries odd? My dispatcherServlet mapped to *.do pattern and jsf servlet mapped to *.jsf. I update topic with a part of web.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX-request is sent as a POST-request, you have to add the HTTP-method into your @RequestMapping-annotation, like @RequestMapping(value="/*.do", method=RequestMethod.POST) . If the "method"-value in the annotation is omitted, it defaults to RequestMethod.GET.

Answer (score 0):

You are using jsf to handle the presentation layer; why are you using spring mvc too? 
You have to use one of them: try using just the faces servlet.

Comment: Can you explain why the OP should use only one of them?